# How do I insert image into database in sqlite3 in python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

conn= sqlite3.connect('Pictures.db')

cur=conn.cursor()

cur.execute('create table pictures(thebin blob)')

file = open('logo4.png', 'rb')

cur.execute('insert into pictures(thebin) values (?)',
[sqlite3.Binary(file.read())])

cur.execute('select thebin from pictures')

file = cur.fetchone()

print(file)

conn.commit()
```

After executing the code, I am getting the output as

> [(b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x07\x80\x00\x00\x048\x08\x02..]

instead of showing an image.

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?